# How to write a query to find a record which is not processed

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle18c

I am trying to write a query from a table A which has 2 columns :

```
ID , STATUS
```

The Status can be `PROCESSING, NOTPROCESSED, FAILED, SUCCESS`

When a record is successfully processed, a new record is created in the DB with STATUS as `PROCESSED` and the ID is the same as the previous `NOTPROCESSED` record.

The Sample Records in DB would like :

```
1      NOTPROCESSED
2      PROCESSED
1      PROCESSED
3      NOTPROCESSED
4      NOTPROCESSED
2      PROCESSED
3      NOTPROCESSED
4      NOTPROCESSED
```

The records can appear as duplicate for `NOTPROCESSED`.

I have to query the records which are `NOTPROCESSED` i.e

```
3      NOTPROCESSED
4      NOTPROCESSED
```

Its getting quite confusing to write the query.

Can anyone help with the logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may use not exists to get this output.

```
select distinct a.id,a.status
  from table a
 where a.status='NOTPROCESSED'
   and not exists (select null
                     from table b
                    where b.id=a.id
                      and b.status='PROCESSED')
```

Comment: This might work as I am creating a View with selected columns from the table with all Unique rows. 

If in some case if the table has all unique rows, how will the query change ?

Comment: the distinct part is used to supress any repeating NONPROCESSED records belonging to the id. If the combination of (id,status) is unique,then the distinct keyword can be removed

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write completely. What i meant to say was suppose there are more columns in the table which will make the ID, STATUS which is Duplicate to unique.
In that case, how will the query change ?

Answer (score 2):

Group by the `id`s and take only those groups having no record of status `PROCESSED`

```
select id
from your_table
group by id
having sum(case when status = 'PROCESSED' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

or get only the ones with only one kind of status

```
having count(distinct status) = 1
```

or use alphabetically the highest status

```
having max(status) = 'NOTPROCESSED'
```

Comment: "`sum(status = 'PROCESSED')`" -- that won't work in Oracle...

Comment: Forgot that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of options:

```
select distinct id from A where id not in (
  select id from A where status = 'PROCESSED'
);

select distinct id from A natural left join (
  select id from A where status = 'PROCESSED'
) as B where B.id is null;
```

Comment: It does seem to work when i execute the query in SQLDeveloper but when I am executing it in my java  code using jdbcTemplate.query, it  still fetches the duplicate record which is processed in the next row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytical function as follows:

```
select * from
(select t.*, count(case when status = 'PROCESSED' then 1 end)
                   over (partition by ID) as cnt
from your_table t) t
where status = 'NOTPROCESSED' and cnt = 0
```